# Compare keys from two different maps

Tags: maps, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to compare two different maps. The first one is a constant in my module:

```
@list_items %{apples: 2, orange: 1, banana: 3}
```

This is acting as `key`: item name, `value`: item price.

Then my function looks like this:

```
def purchase(items) do
  items
  |> Map.merge(@list_items)
end
```

Basically what I want to do is this: if the `items` passed in the function matches any of the keys, it returns a modified map that just contains the matched map and then multiplies the values against each other. This should return the total price based on what is defined in the constant. Here is a test to clarify:

```
test "#purchase/1" do
  assert ProblemModule.purchase(%{apples: 4}) == 8
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `for` to calculate the price of each item, and then sum it using `Enum.sum/1`:

```
Enum.sum(for {name, quantity} <- items, do: list_items[name] * quantity)
```

```
iex(1)> list_items = %{apples: 2, orange: 1, banana: 3}
%{apples: 2, banana: 3, orange: 1}
iex(2)> items = %{apples: 4}
%{apples: 4}
iex(3)> Enum.sum(for {name, quantity} <- items, do: list_items[name] * quantity)
8
iex(4)> items = %{apples: 4, orange: 9}
%{apples: 4, orange: 9}
iex(5)> Enum.sum(for {name, quantity} <- items, do: list_items[name] * quantity)
17
```

Comment: Wow, That's perfect. I was just checking out list comprehensions too!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a fold

```
list_items = %{apples: 2, orange: 1, banana: 3}

purchases = %{apples: 4, orange: 10}

purchases
|> Enum.to_list()
|> List.foldl(0, fn {key, value}, acc ->
  list_items[key] * value + acc
end)
```